# Characterizing the data format of the inputs that an AWK tool processes?

Tags: awk

**AWK newbie here.**

I am trying to characterize (for myself) the data format that an AWK tool expects of the input it processes. (Terminology question: Would such a "data format characterization" be called "AWK's data format model"?) Below is my attempt at a characterization. Is it correct? Is it complete? Is it easy to read and understand? What changes/additions are needed to make it correct, complete, and easy to read/understand?

As an aside: One of the things that I really like about AWK is that the data format of its input is readily described in a few short sentences. That's powerful! Contrast with other common data formats (e.g., XML, JSON, CSV) which require many pages of dense prose.

> The data format consists of lines (lines are strings that are
> typically separated by newlines, although the user may use a symbol
> other than newline, if desired). Each line contains fields. Fields are
> ASCII strings. Fields are separated by a delimiter (common delimiters
> include the tab, space, or comma symbol, although the user is free to
> use another symbol if desired). Fields may contain the field delimiter
> symbol provided the symbol is preceded by a backslash symbol (this is
> called "escaping the symbol"). Fields may be empty. Each line has zero
> or more fields. Lines do not need to have the same number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

> CSV(...)which require many pages of dense prose.

I must protest, CSV is defined by [RFC4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180), *prose* is 7 points inside  **Definition of the CSV Format** at most 2 pages, so I can not say it is *many*.

> Is it complete?

I would say not, because you are using terms without defining them. For example what is *ASCII string* and what is *symbol*?

Comment: Hello @Daweo. That is true, I didn't define ASCII or symbol (nor did I define "string", "delimiter", or "field"). I guess that I am assuming a certain level of understanding on the part of the reader. If I do define ASCII and symbol, then is it correct, complete, and easy to read/understand?

Comment: @RogerCostello I think you should also give default value for field separator, from your current it is not clear how AWK does behave if there is not field separator provided

Comment: @RogerCostello : your characterization is more the typical usage scenario of it, but `awk` is far more than that. e.g. you can directly edit individual bytes in a binary file using `awk` if u like.